# Как обратиться к дочернему элементу под заданным номером при hover?

Tags: html, css

```css
ul {
 width: 200px;
 height: auto;
}

ul > li {
 width: 100%;
 height: 30px;

 background: #fff;

 list-style: none;

 border-bottom: 1px solid #999;

 position: relative;
}


span {
 display: block;

 position: absolute;

 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;

 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li><span>firest</span></li>
 <li><span>second</span></li>
 <li><span>third</span></li>
</ul>
```

Как сделать чтобы при наведении на первый элемент списка у второго текст поменял цвет? И нужно чтобы было сделано при помощи псевдо-классов `:nth-child()` и `:hover`.

Я понял как поменять у первого, но не могу продолжить и поменять у второго..

```
ul > li:nth-child(1):hover {
    color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> при наведении на первый элемент списка у второго текст поменял цвет

```
ul > li:nth-child(1):hover~li:nth-child(2) span,
ul > li:nth-child(2):hover~li:nth-child(3) span{
  color: tomato;
}
```

```css
ul {
 width: 200px;
 height: auto;
}

ul > li {
 width: 100%;
 height: 30px;

 background: #fff;

 list-style: none;

 border-bottom: 1px solid #999;

 position: relative;
}


span {
 display: block;

 position: absolute;

 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;

 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}


ul > li:nth-child(1):hover~li:nth-child(2) span,
ul > li:nth-child(2):hover~li:nth-child(3) span{
  color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li><span>firest</span></li>
 <li><span>second</span></li>
 <li><span>third</span></li>
</ul>
```